# Adding parameter to lambda

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I am using Mustache's Lambda's to implement translations in my templates.

My templates use these kind of tags:

```
<h1>{{#t}}Some translatable text{{/t}}</h1>
```

then, in my data I register a lambda to fetch the translation:

```
$info['t'] = function($text, $render) {
   return translate($text);
}
```

However, I would like to be able to set the locale in that lambda, but I don't seem to get it right:

```
$locale = "nl_NL";
$info['t'] = function($text, $render, $locale) {
   return translate($text, $locale);
}
```

doesn't work (obviously) because Mustache calls this lambda with two parameters. Trying with a default parameter doesn't work either:

```
$lc = "nl_NL";
$info['t'] = function($text, $render, $locale = $lc) {
   return translate($text, $locale);
}
```

Because you cannot use a variable as default.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `use` keyword to bind variables into the function's scope.

Closures may inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header [using use].

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
$locale = "nl_NL";
$info['t'] = function($text, $render) use ($locale) {
   return translate($text, $locale);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think some problem here with the scope of variable,

```
$lc = "nl_NL";
$info['t'] = function($text, $render) use($lc) {
   return translate($text, $lc);
}
```

should solve your problem